# Jquery mobile - How to dynamically create content on pre-existing pages using XML

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-mobile

First time posting here so take it easy with me, lol. I'm currently trying to load content into my "pages" that I have already written the html out for. My jquery script is reading the data in from my xml file content.xml. My first page loads fine, but the pages I'm trying to insert data into it have nothing in them. I've deliberately created each page as a shell to avoid data-url issues.

Here's snippets of my code (lots of repetition so no point in putting it all in):
Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "content.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
});

function xmlParser(xml) {                                                   
    $(xml).find('Phonetic').each(function () {
    var a = 1;
    $test = $("s" +a).append('<div><div class=<div class="S3">' +
            $(this).find("S3").text() + 
            '</div>"S1">' + 
            $(this).find("S1").text() + 
            '</div><div class="S2">' + 
            $(this).find("S2").text() + 
            '</div><div class="S4">' +
            $(this).find("S4").text() + 
            '</div></div>');

    $test.page();
    a++;
});
    }
```

Here's the html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="c1"> 
<div data-role="header"><h1>Test</h1></div> 
<div data-role="content" id="s1"></div> 
<div data-role="footer"><h1>Test release v1.0 - Android tablet test</h1></div> 
</div>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Could I ask what version of jQM are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have just one page, the key is to have pagebeforechange in your document ready or ondeviceready function.

```
$(document).bind("pagebeforecreate",function( e, data ){
      if ( typeof data.toPage === 'string' ){
           var p = $.mobile.path.parseUrl( data.toPage );

           if( u.hash.search( new RegExp( /^MyPageName/ ) ) !== -1 ) {
                $.mobile.showPageLoading();
                MyCodeToExecForThisPage( p, data.options );
                e.preventDefault();  // tell jquery i will create a page not him
           }
      } 
 });
```

so thats your way in, you now need a function to process the page and show the html, here is what i do:

```
function SetPagesTemplate(  ){
$page = $("#AllPage"); // this is the name of my page in the index file
    $header = $page.children( "#AllHead" ); // my header so i can custom change
$content = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=content)" ); // the content area of page
$header.html( 'custom graphic or text' );
$content.html(''); // clear everything up
$footer = $page.children( "#allFoot" ); // hook into my footer bar
$footer.html( 'custom footer nav and links' );
 }
```

below is code to show when navigating to a page that nees a value  for example  #person?personid=22    my page is person  and i will be taking the id [ personid ] and getting the correct info, i will then populate my ALLPAGES  page with the content and make jquery think i am actually on #person.

```
 // take note here that i take in urlObj [ this was p ]  and options
function LoadPerson( urlObj, options ) {
  try{
// lets get the number sent by stripping everything out
    var id = urlObj.hash.replace( /.*personid=/,"" ),
    extra = "";
SetPagesTemplate(  ); // the code that sets the page so i dont have to repeat myself.

$.ajax({
    url: "http:\/\/" + domain + "/Ajax/MobilePersonProfile",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { id: id },
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function ( data ) {
        //loop through data create rows
        if( data.length === 0 ){ ThrowCustomAlert( 'Sorry, unable to load profile.', 'no profile available', true ); } 
        else { 

            // now deal with your data on this example your processed data would be called template
                    // all this page stuff was set up earlier so lets fill it
            $content.append("<section><nav id='profilescroll'>" + extra + template + "</nav></section>" );
            $page.page(); // make our page into a page
            options.dataUrl = urlObj.href;
            template = null;
            data = null;
              // above cleanup, on mobile device to keep memory leaks low
                            // now we navigate to our created page THIS
            $.mobile.changePage( $page, options );


            StartScroller( "profilescroll" );
            HideLoading(); // lets hide the page loading
        }
    },
    error: function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { CustomError(errorThrown,'',"Profile",true); }
});
}
catch( ee ){ CustomError( ee.message, ee.description, "profile", true ); }
```

}

thats all you need, its all i ever use, i dont think i have seen examples like this i have had to basically turn my entire app into this way of working to reduce the memory usage on iphone 2 when using as a phonegap app, and it is very very very quick with full ajax navigation.

points to note is that you only need hashtag navigation,   in your pagebeforecreate  set up a new if for every page you want.   w

well hope it helps

as requested here is the html for my page:

```
 <div data-role="page" id="AllPage" class="body" style="overflow:hidden;">

  <header class="bar" id="AllHead"></header>

  <div data-role="content" class="content" id="home"></div><!-- /content -->

  <footer class="bar" id="allFoot"></footer>

 </div><!-- /page -->
```

Comment: Is it possibly to provide the html so I can step through it? I think I've got my head around it!

Comment: i have amended my post, basically whatever html you create goes into $content,   you need to declare var $page, $content, $header, $footer;  globally at the top of your js file that you use for processing pages.

Comment: just as a note, you will find things way easier if you switch from xml to json if possible,  jquery handles json so well these days.

Comment: You're right, it is much easier with json so after your suggestion I've changed over to it! Thanks for the html, I'm about to try it out now but it finally makes sense. Many thanks!

Looking at your json, could you simplify it using the .getJSON call instead? I'm calling from local and have json working that way at the moment.

Comment: i suppose i like to use the .ajax i find it easier to use with regards to errors handling etc, plus most of my stuff is post rather than get as i pass over a session key to my server to get user info.  if your happy then mark as answer :-)

Comment: I tried using this yesterday, even replicated your example and it refuses to load any content. What version of Jquerymobile are you using? The example on their website loads fine but that's only on the first version of the script.

Comment: latest one from jquery mobile, then above code was from jquery beta 3

Comment: also make sure you do console.log on each section so you can see where it gets to and ensure everything runs

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and following solution worked for me:

1. Store your pages into a global array
2. change your anchors to look like this: `<a href='javascript:change_page(1)' />` where 1 is replaced by the index of your page.
3. then define `.change_page()` method and call `jquery.mobile.changePage(arr[index]);` to navigate to your dynamically added page.

Regards.